# Getting a value from json to insert in another function js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, css, animation

I would like to pass a value from a function to a " value: " to animate

pass to here specifically where said **"Value: 12"** replace the value for the result of the json

```
var updateJackpots = function()
{
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.ganegrande.do/ajax/getjackpots',
        cache: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

            var total = 0; $('#total').remove();

            //update the jackpots
            $(data).each(function(i, el)
            {   
                total += getMoneyValue(el.formatted_value);
            });

            //update the total
            $('<div id="total"/>').html(''+commaFormatted(parseFloat(total).toFixed(2))).appendTo('body');


            //update jackpots again after 30 seconds
            setTimeout(updateJackpots, 864000000);
        },
        error: function(i,a,e)
        {
            alert(i + a + e);
        }
    });
}; updateJackpots();
...

function loadCounter(){
    customCounter = new Counter("customCounter", {
        ...,
        value : 12 <!-- HERE SHOULD GO THE JSON RESULT "2544423.11" AUTOMATICALLY -->
    });

    customTimerId = window.setInterval(function(){
        ...
    }, 2050); 
}

loadCounter();

});
```

**The full code is in the following fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/JoelGarcia/jL3fn/14/

Comment: You could show us only important code, this way you just confuse people who want to help you

Comment: Ok, sorry!!! im So tired bro.  i will take an account thanks any way

Comment: be careful: 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000 < 10000000000000000000000000000000000000001 = false :))

Comment: Take a look at jQuery's $.ajax() http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. You can use it to get JSON (or any other data) from a webserver. Mind that it might be blocked to other servers by your browser to prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: THOSE NUMBER JUST IS FOR TESTING " Igor Benikov "

Comment: So the mean is that im a noob with this and i dont know how use that, the json feed is fine take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/JoelGarcia/jL3fn/14/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I think this is what you want. I have added a `counterCreated` variable, so when the ajax call comes back, if there is no counter it creates one, otherwise it updates the current counter value. See http://jsfiddle.net/jL3fn/21/

Alternatively, you can create the counter with a value of 0, and then update it when the ajax call comes back. See http://jsfiddle.net/jL3fn/22/

Comment: No, i want animate the json result " 2544424.09 " but to animate that i need to get the value and put it result in value : 12  <-- HERE SHOULD GO THE JSON RESULT AUTOMATICALLY TO ANIMATE

Comment: Have a look at the code, I think I've done what you have asked.

Comment: Sorry Fred no yet, where said "latestUpdate" i would like to see the amount of json result that's all could be posible?

Comment: only problem that borks up when you hit the updateJackPots timer again it will actually just create a new timer underneath the previous timer

Comment: So you want it to update the value! Your original question is misleading. http://jsfiddle.net/jL3fn/21/

Comment: Thanks to all especially to **FRED**. Finally!!  i got my result you are amazing. Now is running as I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what the end goal is here, but I think you want to load with the jackpot total then starting counting up by some number, not sure what else beyond that.

I added an `non async` call to the `updateJackPots` method in order to wait until the value is populated then creating the counter.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jL3fn/20/)